# Get notebook outline in sagemaker studio like in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

When I use visual studio code with jupyter notebook, I have an "outline" tab in the left panels that display the Markdown section of my notebook for quick access.

But in Sagemaker studio I don't have this and I would like to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'Outline' tab (Table of Contents extension in Jupyter) is not available for Studio yet.

[SageMaker notebook instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html) come with the extension prebuilt.

Comment: Old post but adding - Table of contents is now built-in to Studio notebooks as well.